# How to accept objects as inputs and iterate over their keys in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I'm building a function that takes an object where keys are addresses and values are amounts to be paid to those addresses.

The function needs to make payments to the addresses based on the values.

The input example:

```
{
  0x5b12sb2523c...: 3,
  0x7328acbc625...: 4,
  0x127v26dsc12...: 1,
         ...
}
```

How can I construct it? Can a solidity function accept an object like that and if yes how to iterate over the keys to make the payment to each of them?

```
function payRewards(object arguments) public {
   ...
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a type as `Object` in solidity. Instead, you can pass two arrays to `payRewards` function representing addresses and amounts to pay. Something like  this:

```
function payRewards(address[] memory users, uint256[] memory amounts) {
    // iterate over users and amounts
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, can't believe I haven't thought about that! Thank you.